# hotmail/live mail missing document attachments like bank statements

Tags: email, hotmail, windows-live-mail

I am using windows hotmail for the past few years, and recently the layout of hotmail is changed. along with the layout, now i am not able to see the documents in the mail attachments which are received from banks/credit cards. Don't know if anyone else is facing this issue. See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErRxR.png) below which is showing documents but the actual attachment is missing from the mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and just found out what caused it. In my case I am using Google Chrome and use Adblock. After excluding the outlook.live.com domain from Adblock the attachment returned. I hope this helps you too.

Comment: Thanks, i am able to see the attachments after removing the adblock.